# How do I return a Game to Full Screen?

Tags: windows-10

I have a Microsoft wireless keyboard.  There is a switch on the keyboard that changes the function keys between 'F1-10' and things like volume up and down buttons.  One of the special functions, represented by a magnifying glass, open up the windows search function.  It is also on the same key as F5 (which is quick save in many games).  I often switch between modes to do things such as adjust volume.

My problem is that if I hit that key while in the 'special function' mode while in a full screen game it opens my the search program and takes my full screen game to a window.  I then can't return the game to full screen mode.

I've tried `F11`, I've tried `Alt+Enter`, I've tried `Win+Shift+Enter`.  Those are things that worked for me in previous editions of Windows or that I've read that work in Windows 10 but none of them do the trick.  This is a problem for me in multiple games from different studios so I don't think this problem is game specific.

How do I return a game to full screen?

Comment: I think you will find this behavior varies between games. Is there an option to run it in borderless windowed mode, with the same res as your desktop?

Comment: There are several options in the games graphics settings.  I have it set to full screen.  This is how it starts.  I only have a problem when I hit that damn key by accident.  Then its in a window and I can't revert without restarting the game.  As stated, it seems to be a problem with a number of games.